# Sloped pieces in winter scene

Tags: part-identification

I'm trying to build a winter scene similar to [this scene](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bigboy99899/31635591151/).  Can anyone identify the large sloped/curved white pieces on the rivers edge, near the bottom of the picture?

[image: Snow scene]

Comment: Looks like a digital render, not a real life build. Which means parts could be used that do not exist in a particular color in LEGO’s catalog.

Comment: It is a gorgeous picture, but to add to Phil's comment: I don't see any edges between the tiles on the "lake" or the "ground" which I don't think is possible with real pieces.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like [Windscreen 6 x 4 x 1 Curved](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18973). This piece doesn't come in any of opaque colors yet.

[image]

Comment: Nothing a little paint can't fix, which you'd probably want to do anyhow to get that snowy texture across this entire piece.  (This looks like the kind of thing you'd build as a permanent rather than being able to take it apart and reuse the pieces later anyhow.)